# Android frame animation leaving trailing afterimages

Tags: java, android, animation

My first post on Stack Overflow. I'm using a book to learn some Android game programming (Android Game Programming in 24 Hours, by Jonathan Harbour). Anyways, when I updated this Sprite class for a simple animation demo, I end up with a number of strange afterimages in my emulator:
[screenshot of emulator, using new code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGkVN.png). The afterimages (or whatever they're called, previous frame images) remain on the screen even as the animations continue on to the next frame. The cat on the right and the kitty on the top left are affected, but apparently the horse image is not.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I'm just copying exactly from the book. I have rechecked it multiple times. Here is the code that *does not* work. The changes to the Sprite class compared to the previous version have //--** at the end of each line (for convenience, I don't know how to bold code blocks).

.

```
/**
* Sprite class
* Requires game.engine.Engine to build
*/

package game.engine;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import android.graphics.*;

// added for frame scratch bitmap
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;   //--**

public class Sprite
{
    private Engine p_engine;
    private Canvas p_canvas;
    private Texture p_texture;
    private Paint p_paint;
    public Point position;

    private int p_width, p_height;
    private int p_columns;
    private int p_alpha;
    private LinkedList<Animation> p_anims;
    private int p_frame;
    private Float2 p_scale;
    private float p_rotation;   // note this is in radians

    private Matrix p_mat_translate;   //--**
    private Matrix p_mat_scale;   //--**
    private Matrix p_mat_rotate; //--**
    private Matrix p_matrix;   //--**
    private Bitmap p_frameBitmap;   //--**
    private Canvas p_frameCanvas;   //--**


    public Sprite(Engine engine)
    {
        this(engine, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    public Sprite(Engine engine, int width, int height, int columns)
    {
        p_engine = engine;
        p_width = width;
        p_height = height;
        p_columns = columns;
        p_canvas = null;
        p_texture = new Texture(engine);
        p_alpha = 255;
        p_paint = new Paint();
        p_anims = new LinkedList<Animation>();
        position = new Point(0, 0);
        p_frame = 0;
        p_scale = new Float2(1.0f, 1.0f);
        p_rotation = 0.0f;

        p_mat_translate = new Matrix();   //--**
        p_mat_scale = new Matrix();   //--**
        p_mat_rotate = new Matrix();   //--**
        p_matrix = new Matrix();   //--**
        p_frameBitmap = null;   //--**
        p_frameCanvas = null;   //--**
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        p_canvas = p_engine.getCanvas();

        // fill in size if this sprite is not animated
        if (p_width == 0 || p_height == 0)
        {
            p_width = p_texture.getBitmap().getWidth();
            p_height = p_texture.getBitmap().getHeight();
        }

        // create the frame scratch bitmap
        if (p_frameBitmap == null)
        {
            p_frameBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(p_width, p_height, Config.ARGB_8888); //--**
            p_frameCanvas = new Canvas(p_frameBitmap);   //--**
        }

        /**
         * First, copy the animation frame onto a scratch bitmap.
        */

        // define the source rect representing one frame
        int u = (p_frame % p_columns) * p_width;
        int v = (p_frame / p_columns) * p_height;
        Rect src = new Rect(u, v, u+p_width, v+p_height);

        // define the destination location
        int x = 0; //position.x;   //--**
        int y = 0; //position.y;   //--**
        int w = p_width; //(int) (p_width * p_scale.x);   //--**
        int h = p_height; //(int) (p_height * p_scale.y);   //--**
        Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x+w, y+h);

        // copy frame onto temp bitmap
        p_paint.setAlpha(p_alpha);
        p_frameCanvas.drawBitmap(p_texture.getBitmap(), src, dst, p_paint); //--**


        /**
         * Second, draw the scratch bitmap using matrix transforms.
         */

        // update transform matrices
        p_mat_scale = new Matrix();   //--**
        p_mat_scale.setScale(p_scale.x, p_scale.y);  //--**
        p_mat_rotate = new Matrix();   //--**
        p_mat_rotate.setRotate( (float) Math.toDegrees(p_rotation) ); //--**
        p_mat_translate = new Matrix();   //--**
        p_mat_translate.setTranslate(position.x, position.y);   //--**
        p_matrix = new Matrix(); // set to identity   //--**
        p_matrix.postConcat(p_mat_scale);  //--**
        p_matrix.postConcat(p_mat_rotate);   //--**
        p_matrix.postConcat(p_mat_translate);   //--**

        // draw frame bitmap onto screen
        p_canvas.drawBitmap(p_frameBitmap, p_matrix, p_paint);   //--**

    }

    // add an animation technique to this sprite
    public void addAnimation(Animation anim)
    {
        p_anims.add(anim);
    }

    // run through all of the animations
    public void animate()
    {
        if (p_anims.size() == 0) return;

        ListIterator<Animation> iterator = p_anims.listIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Animation anim = iterator.next();
            if (anim.animating)
            {
                p_frame = anim.adjustFrame(p_frame);
                p_alpha = anim.adjustAlpha(p_alpha);
                p_rotation = anim.adjustRotation(p_rotation);
                p_scale = anim.adjustScale(p_scale);
                position = anim.adjustPosition(position);
            }
            else
            {
                p_anims.remove(anim);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Color manipulation methods
     */
    public void setAlpha(int alpha)
    {
        p_alpha = alpha;
    }

    public int getAlpha()
    {
        return p_alpha;
    }

    public void setPaint(Paint paint)
    {
        p_paint = paint;
    }

    /**
     * common get/set methods
     */
    public void setTexture(Texture texture)
    {
        p_texture = texture;
    }

    public Texture getTexture()
    {
        return p_texture;
    }

    public void setPosition(Point position)
    {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Point getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }

    public int getWidth()
    {
        return p_width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width)
    {
        p_width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight()
    {
        return p_height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height)
    {
        p_height = height;
    }

    public Point getSize()
    {
        return new Point(p_width, p_height);
    }

    public int getFrame()
    {
        return p_frame;
    }

    public void setFrame(int frame)
    {
        p_frame = frame;
    }

    public Float2 getScale()
    {
        return p_scale;
    }

    public void setScale(Float2 scale)
    {
        p_scale = scale;
    }

    public void setScale(float scale)
    {
        p_scale = new Float2(scale, scale);
    }

    public float getRotation()
    {
        return p_rotation;
    }

    public void setRotation(float radians)
    {
        p_rotation = radians;
    }
}
```

I thought the problem might be bitmaps and how they're drawn or matrices. I tried using `p_frameBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

at the end of the draw() method, like this:

```
        ...
        // draw frame bitmap onto screen
        p_canvas.drawBitmap(p_frameBitmap, p_matrix, p_paint);

        // attempt to clear the scratch bitmap
        p_frameBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    }
    ...
```

This got rid of the trailing images, but instead, the kitty on the top left flashes from white to orange back to white, which appears to be the color of the big cat on the right: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoJDw.png). I can't figure out why.

I have also tried using `p_frameCanvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);` with the corresponding import statement `import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;`, but the result (flashing orange) is the same.

Here is the code (previous version) that *does* work:

```
/**
* Sprite class
* Requires game.engine.Engine to build
*/

package game.engine;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import android.graphics.*;

public class Sprite
{
    private Engine p_engine;
    private Canvas p_canvas;
    private Texture p_texture;
    private Paint p_paint;
    public Point position;

    private int p_width, p_height;
    private int p_columns;
    private int p_alpha;
    private LinkedList<Animation> p_anims;
    private int p_frame;
    private Float2 p_scale;
    private float p_rotation;   // note this is in radians

    public Sprite(Engine engine)
    {
        this(engine, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    public Sprite(Engine engine, int width, int height, int columns)
    {
        p_engine = engine;
        p_width = width;
        p_height = height;
        p_columns = columns;
        p_canvas = null;
        p_texture = new Texture(engine);
        p_alpha = 255;
        p_paint = new Paint();
        p_anims = new LinkedList<Animation>();
        position = new Point(0, 0);
        p_frame = 0;
        p_scale = new Float2(1.0f, 1.0f);
        p_rotation = 0.0f;
    }

    public void draw()
    {
        p_canvas = p_engine.getCanvas();

        // fill in size if this sprite is not animated
        if (p_width == 0 || p_height == 0)
        {
            p_width = p_texture.getBitmap().getWidth();
            p_height = p_texture.getBitmap().getHeight();
        }

        // define the source rect representing one frame
        int u = (p_frame % p_columns) * p_width;
        int v = (p_frame / p_columns) * p_height;
        Rect src = new Rect(u, v, u+p_width, v+p_height);

        // define the destination location
        int x = position.x;
        int y = position.y;
        int w = (int) (p_width * p_scale.x);
        int h = (int) (p_height * p_scale.y);
        Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x+w, y+h);

        p_paint.setAlpha(p_alpha);

        //draw the frame
        p_canvas.drawBitmap(p_texture.getBitmap(), src, dst, p_paint);
    }

    // add an animation technique to this sprite
    public void addAnimation(Animation anim)
    {
        p_anims.add(anim);
    }

    // run through all of the animations
    public void animate()
    {
        if (p_anims.size() == 0) return;

        ListIterator<Animation> iterator = p_anims.listIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Animation anim = iterator.next();
            if (anim.animating)
            {
                p_frame = anim.adjustFrame(p_frame);
                p_alpha = anim.adjustAlpha(p_alpha);
                p_rotation = anim.adjustRotation(p_rotation);
                p_scale = anim.adjustScale(p_scale);
                position = anim.adjustPosition(position);
            }
            else
            {
                p_anims.remove(anim);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Color manipulation methods
     */
    public void setAlpha(int alpha)
    {
        p_alpha = alpha;
    }

    public int getAlpha()
    {
        return p_alpha;
    }

    public void setPaint(Paint paint)
    {
        p_paint = paint;
    }

    /**
     * common get/set methods
     */
    public void setTexture(Texture texture)
    {
        p_texture = texture;
    }

    public Texture getTexture()
    {
        return p_texture;
    }

    public void setPosition(Point position)
    {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Point getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }

    public int getWidth()
    {
        return p_width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width)
    {
        p_width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight()
    {
        return p_height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height)
    {
        p_height = height;
    }

    public Point getSize()
    {
        return new Point(p_width, p_height);
    }

    public int getFrame()
    {
        return p_frame;
    }

    public void setFrame(int frame)
    {
        p_frame = frame;
    }

    public Float2 getScale()
    {
        return p_scale;
    }

    public void setScale(Float2 scale)
    {
        p_scale = scale;
    }

    public void setScale(float scale)
    {
        p_scale = new Float2(scale, scale);
    }

    public float getRotation()
    {
        return p_rotation;
    }

    public void setRotation(float radians)
    {
        p_rotation = radians;
    }

}
```

In any case, I have been stuck on this for a long time. I'm fairly new to Java, so simple explanations are appreciated.

**TL;DR:** The Sprite class I'm using is creating a trail of afterimages for some of my animations. This didn't happen in a previous version of the class. When I try clearing the bitmap, the trailing images disappear but bizarrely one of the animations begins to flash a different color. Not familiar with bitmaps and matrices.

Other info:

The actual class being run is a different class, called Game. I know normally you'd include the whole source code, with all the different classes being run together, but there are at least 15 different classes being used here (because the book is teaching you how to build a game engine from scratch). The Sprite class and similar helper classes (Engine, Canvas, Texture, Animation, etc.) are in a separate package, "game.engine". Here is the Game class that is actually run on the emulator:

```
/**
 * Animation System Demo
 * Requires game.engine.Engine to build
 */

import android.graphics.*;
import game.engine.*;

public class Game extends game.engine.Engine
{

    Canvas canvas;
    Timer timer;
    Sprite kitty;
    Texture kitty_image;
    Sprite horse;
    Texture horse_image;
    Sprite runningCat;
    Texture runningCat_image;
    Sprite ship;
    Texture ship_image;

public Game()
{
    canvas = null;
    timer = new Timer();
    kitty = null;
    kitty_image = null;
    horse = null;
    horse_image = null;
    runningCat = null;
    runningCat_image = null;
    ship = null;
    ship_image = null;

}

public void init() {
    setScreenOrientation(Engine.ScreenModes.LANDSCAPE);

}

public void load() {
    /**
     * create kitty sprite
     */
    kitty = new Sprite(this, 32, 32, 12);
    kitty_image = new Texture(this);

    if (!kitty_image.loadFromAsset("cutekitties.png"))
    {
        fatalError("Error loading cutekitties");
    }
    kitty.setTexture(kitty_image);
    kitty.position = new Point(20, 60);
    kitty.setAlpha(0);

    /**
     * create horse sprite
     */
    horse = new Sprite(this, 152, 154, 4);
    horse_image = new Texture(this);
    if (!horse_image.loadFromAsset("horserunning.png"))
    {
        fatalError("Error loading horserunning");
    }
    horse.setTexture(horse_image);
    horse.position = new Point(20, 260);

    /**
     * create running cat sprite
     */
    runningCat = new Sprite(this, 512, 256, 2);
    runningCat_image = new Texture(this);
    if (!runningCat_image.loadFromAsset("runningcat.png"))
    {
        fatalError("Error loading runningcat");
    }
    runningCat.setTexture(runningCat_image);
    runningCat.position = new Point(300, 90);

    /**
     * create ship sprite (NO FRAMES)
     */
    ship = new Sprite(this);
    ship_image = new Texture(this);
    if (!ship_image.loadFromAsset("ship1.png"))
    {
        fatalError("Error loading ship1");
    }
    ship.setTexture(ship_image);
    ship.position = new Point(300, 300);
    ship.setScale(0.5f);

    /**
     * add animation techniques to the sprites
     */

    kitty.addAnimation(new FrameAnimation(12, 14, 1));
    kitty.addAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(0, 255, 5));

    horse.addAnimation(new FrameAnimation(0, 7, 1));
    horse.addAnimation(new ThrobAnimation(0.5f, 3.0f, 0.01f));

    runningCat.addAnimation(new FrameAnimation(0, 7, 1));
    runningCat.addAnimation(new CircularMovementAnimation(
            runningCat.position.x, runningCat.position.y, 
            60, 0.0, 0.1f) );

    ship.addAnimation(new ThrobAnimation(0.2f, 1.5f, 0.1f));
}

public void draw() {
    canvas = getCanvas();
    drawText("Animation System Demo", 10, 20);

    // draw the kitty
    kitty.draw();
    int x = kitty.position.x;
    int y = kitty.position.y + 128;
    drawText("Frame: " + toString(kitty.getFrame()), x, y);
    drawText("Alpha: " + kitty.getAlpha(), x, y+30);

    // draw the horse
    horse.draw();
    x = horse.position.x;
    y = horse.position.y + 128;
    drawText("Frame: " + horse.getFrame(), x, y);
    drawText("Scale: " + toString(horse.getScale()), x, y+30);

    // draw the running cat
    runningCat.draw();
    x = runningCat.position.x;
    y = runningCat.position.y + 128;
    drawText("Frame: " + runningCat.getFrame(), x, y);
    drawText("Pos: " + toString(runningCat.position.x) + ", " + 
            toString(runningCat.position.y), x, y+30);

    // draw the ship
    ship.draw();
    x = ship.position.x;
    y = ship.position.y+128;
    drawText("Pos: " + toString(ship.position.x) + ", " +
            toString(ship.position.y), x, y+30);
}

public void update() {

    // set animation to 50 fps
    if (timer.stopwatch(20))    //ms, 20 milliseconds per frame, 50 frames in 1 second
    {

        // update kitty animation
        kitty.animate();

        // reset alpha animation
        if (kitty.getAlpha() >= 255)
        {
            kitty.setAlpha(0);
            kitty.addAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(0, 255, 1));
        }

        // update horse animation
        horse.animate();

        // reset throb animation
        if (horse.getScale().x <= 0.5f)
        {
            horse.addAnimation(new ThrobAnimation(0.5f, 3.0f, 0.01f));
        }

        // update running cat animation
        runningCat.animate();

        // update ship animation
        ship.animate();

        // reset throb animation
        if (ship.getScale().x <= 0.2f)
        {
            ship.addAnimation(new ThrobAnimation(0.2f, 1.5f, 0.1f));
        }


    }

}

//end of class
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem you are having is due to the animations that you are adding. Have you tried running your code without adding them and comparing the results?

Comment: That's possible. I'm using [this white kitty][3] and [this running cat][4]. I'll look into it, thanks!
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ir61.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrUoq.png

Comment: Okay, I figured some things out. 1) The trailing images only occur when I use images/bitmaps with transparent backgrounds, and 2) when I use p_frameBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); the trailing images disappear, but my alpha animation, which changes the image from transparent to solid, repeatedly changes the image's color around the 200 - 255 alpha value range. The alpha animation works fine with non-transparent images though. So it looks like I need a different solution other than p_frameBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); to use the alpha animation for any image.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with color values. The alpha animation on a plain white image still flashes color, gradually from orange to (when close to 255) yellow.